# Python: Command Prompt File

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, nameerror

I've written a program called pyramid.py and I'm trying to access it from the command prompt.

So far I've tried typing the name out: Resulting in a NameError

[image: Here]

And I tried dragging the file into the window: Resulting in a SyntaxError

[image: Here]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please type out the messages instead of including images.

Answer (score 1):

You give the script file as an argument to the `python` command:

```
C:\Users\Parker>python3 pyramid.py
```